# Java For Statement

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
StringBuilder[] remoteFiles = {filesRemote};

for (StringBuilder i : remoteFiles) {
    System.out.println("This is: " + i);
}
```

It Returns:

```
This is file1
file2
file3
```

Instead of:

```
This is file1
This is file2
This is file3
```

How can I get it to print as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringBuilder[] remoteFiles = {filesRemote};` defines an array of `StringBuilder`, that has exactly one element. The behaviour is expected. You may want to try something like this:

```
String[] remoteFiles = filesRemote.toString().split("\n"); // replace "\n" with the separator, i just guesstimated it.
for (String s : remoteFiles) {
    System.out.println("This is: " + s);
}
```